# Does the best model necessarily have the best results on validation set?

Tags: overfitting, fitting

During the fine-tunning of a DistilBert model, I tried two optimizers (with different parameter sets) on the same dataset.

Here are the results:

```
- AdamW: train loss (0.21), val loss (0.33), accuracy (0.88)
- SGD: train loss (0.35), val loss (0.35), accuracy (0.87)
```

I read that if:

```
- train loss > val loss: the model is under-fitted
- train loss == val loss: the model is well-fitted
- train loss < val loss: the model is over-fitted
```

So I would say that the model trained with AdamW is over-fitted, but on the other end it is (slightly) better.

Should I prefer a well-fitted model with a slight loss of validation results, or should I focus only on the best validation results?

Comment: What do you mean by “KPI” here?

Comment: Validation loss and accuracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A training loss which is lower than the validation loss doesn't necessarily indicate an overfitted model. Overfitting should be a concern when the validation loss stops improving or actually deteriorates with further model training. There are a number of reasons why training loss might be persistently lower than validation loss and in fact this is typically the case.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what you are describing *are not* KPIs. KPIs are usually [business metrics for the problem you are trying to solve](https://medium.com/mercadolibre-tech/no-machine-learning-kpis-first-935e8ca0e4a9). They do not have to do anything with the machine learning metrics. Using those terms interchangeably would be confusing for many people. If indeed you had a *key* performance indicator, it would be a key metric for your project, so it would be decisive by itself.

Second, your definitions of underfitting and overfitting are not correct. Metrics are real-valued, so there is literally zero probability that training and test metrics would be equal. As @Estacionario noticed in their answer, test metrics would *usually* be worse than the training metrics because they are calculated on unseen data. We are talking about underfitting or overfitting if those differences are significant (there is no formal threshold) and/or based on other criteria.

Finally, consider a more extreme case, where you have two models: the first one has 50% train and 50% test accuracy, while the other has 90% train and 80% test accuracy. Which would you choose? The consistently poor one does not sound like a great choice.